# Is there a way to subclass using an alternate constructor class method?

Tags: python, class, methods, parent-child, class-method

For example, say I have a parent class:

```
class Foo:
 def __init__(self, x, y):
  self.x = x
  self.y = y

 @classmethod
 def special_pointx(cls, y):
  return cls(1, y)
```

And then I wanted to create a subclass of Foo using the `special_pointx` classmethod constructor.  Is there a way to do that?

My initial thoughts would be something like:

```
class Bar(Foo.special_pointx):
 pass
```

But in this case I wouldn't know how to pass in the argument to special_pointx, and anyways I get a TypeError saying "method expected 2 arguments, got 3".  So then I tried:

```
class Bar(Foo):
 def __init__(self, y, z):
  self.z = z
  super(Bar, self).special_pointx(y)
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.  I get the error: "special_pointx() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given."  Any help would be appreciated.  I would expect the end result to be a class Bar that has the attributes x = 1, y = y, and z = z.

Edit: Seems like I was missing cls in the special_pointx definition originally (thanks ewong), which is why I was getting those positional argument errors, but now with that fixed I am getting a RecursionError between __init__ and special_pointx.  I would expect special_pointx to be calling Foo.__init__, but it seems like it is calling Bar.__init__ instead?

Comment: in your special_pointx() definition, you're missing ```cls``` in the parameters.  i.e. ```def special_pointx(cls, y)```

Comment: Thanks!  Just a dumb mistake I made.  That seems to have fixed the positional argument problem I was having, but now I am getting a RecursionError, specifically between __init__ and special_pointx?